# Illegal input character "\342" in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Getting illegal character \342 error on the "29" at the end of the below query and cant find any documentation as why. Note that store_num is a string in the source table.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE store_num = '27082​29'
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you copied the code from another document that tool that char with copy/paste. Just go to that position and delete that char (it will be invisible)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I copied the query from slack. After pasting it into the BigQuery console I received the described error message.
To circumvent this, I pasted the query first in sublime, which showed "​​​<0x200>" in the empty lines. I deletes these tags and copied the query again and insert it in to my console. The execution ran without any issues.