dbt Model in VS Code: Error 'Illegal input character \303' with BigQuery
I'm using dbt with VS Code to build a model on BigQuery. I'm encountering the following error:
Syntax error: Illegal input character "\\303" at \[24:15\]
This is my script. I've already tried the following steps:

Checked the code for any non-printable or hidden characters.

Ensured that my file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Removed any special formatting by copying the code to a plain text editor.


{{ config(
    tags=["PII", "LAGERL23B"],
    materialized="table"
) }}

WITH
    -- Quell-Daten laden und alle Transformationen in einer einzigen CTE durchführen
    Extraktion_Details AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            CONCAT(
                SUBSTRING(CAST(Artikelfarbennummer AS STRING), 1, 2), '-', 
                SUBSTRING(CAST(Artikelfarbennummer AS STRING), 3, 4), '/', 
                SUBSTRING(CAST(Artikelfarbennummer AS STRING), 7, 2)
            ) AS Artikelnummer,
            SUBSTRING(CAST(Artikelfarbennummer AS STRING), 7, 2) AS Farbnummer,
            SUBSTRING(CAST(Artikelfarbennummer AS STRING), 1, 6) AS Artikelnummer_ohne_Farbe,
            SUBSTRING(CAST(FORM8 AS STRING), 1, 2) AS PROD2
        FROM {{ ref("stg_LAGERL23B") }} AS LAGERL23B
    ),

    Neuer_Schlüssel AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            CONCAT(Kundennummer, '_', PROD2) AS Key_Kunde
        FROM Extraktion_Details 
    )

-- Finaler Output
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Neuer_Schlüssel


Any help would be appreciated!

Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273921/illegal-input-character-342-in-google-bigquery

The umlaut in your alias is causing an issue in BigQuery.  You can remove/replace it or wrap the alias in tickmarks if you prefer to keep it:
with `Neuer_Schlüssel` as (
  select 123 as abc
)
select * from `Neuer_Schlüssel`


The German language characters ä, ö and ü are not recognized by dbt. repalce ü with ue in your CTE.
